# Token Total Supply Issue at Etherscan - Please Help!

Tags: etherscan, totalsupply

Please help. I have deployed the token contract but forgot to setup the public visibility for the total supply. Now Etherscan cannot show/prove the total supply of the token.

Basically, I used the code: "uint256 constant **private** MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;"

instead of "uint256 constant **public** MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;"

The token has been deployed and already tradable, so no way to redeploy the contract ...

My question is how critical is this issue and most importantly, how can token holders verify the total supply of the token? Are there any user friendly ways to do this? I guess that listing sites such as Coingecko and Coinmarketcap as well as exchanges will also have this question...

Please help if you can!!!

Comment: Why use the name `MAX_UINT256` for total supply?

Comment: This is not your max supply, or if it is i'd be very concerned because Uniswap can't handle numbers that big and trading is gonna break eventually (once there is enough tokens in the LP).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bonus 0.05 $ETH for Help: "totalSupply" shows extra 18 zeroes on Etherscan in Read Contract section (UPDATED)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/139910/bonus-0-05-eth-for-help-totalsupply-shows-extra-18-zeroes-on-etherscan-in-re)

Answer (score 1):

You can 'easily' get a private state variable with an api like web3.eth.getStorageAt(tokenAddress, varLocation).

But it's not user friendly per say.

You need to contact Coingecko and CoinMarkercap supports and see with them.

Also, verify and publish your contract on etherscan so you can show how you set up your private variable.